# The value of Signing Identity is "-" when I execute the command react-native run-ios on simulator

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native

When I run command `react-native run-ios` from my terminal the app crash after load dependencies from Metro Bundler. I mean, the app opens, the green background on the top with the label  "Loading from localhost: 8081" appears, and then the app close itself.

If I run `react-native run-ios --configuration Debug --device "My iPhone's Name"` with my iPhone connected the app works with no problem.

I don't know why it doesn't work then on the simulator but, I could see a difference. When the app is building on the terminal, it can be see the message Signing Identity with a value.

In the case that I ran the app in my device the value is my account from apple, something like: `Signing Identity: "iPhone Developer: myname@******(I won't put here my credentials) "`.

If I use the command `react-native run-ios` to open the App in the simulator the message of Signing Identity is these: `Signing Identity: "-"`.

It seems the problem is around this. Do you have any Idea of what could it be?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm facing similar issue.

Comment: I did, I don't remember what I did to fix it but I was a foolishness. If I remember it I will post it here.